# Devise w/ Subdirectories in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I'm building a rails application in which I need to support multiple tenants via:

```
example.com/:tenant_1
example.com/:tenant_2
```

For each of these tenants I would like to have separate logins:

```
example.com/:tenant_1/sign_in
example.com/:tenant_2/sign_in
```

For each tenant I would like their login session to be scoped to the applicable tenant subdirectory. Is this something that devise supports and if so how would one go about implementing this?

Comment: Creating two models with devise should be enough, for example `User` and `Admin`

Comment: If you are able to use subdomains instead of subdirectories, Devise includes a HOWTO at https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-to:-Scope-login-to-subdomain

Comment: @JimVanFleet Unfortunately I'm not able to use subdomains (business/above my pay grade reasons).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Devise will support the authentication if you have the model and `sessions` set up properly.

--

What you're doing is very similar to if you had a [`subdomain`](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Use-subdomains):

```
#config/routes.rb
scope Tenant do
   root "application#dashboard"
   devise_for :users, controllers: {}
end

#lib/tenant.rb
module CompanyDispatch

    def initializer(router)
        @router = router
    end

    def self.matches?(request)
        Account.exists? request.path.split("/").first
    end

end
```

The above will give you the ability to access `url.com/:tenant_1/sign_in` (might need tweaking etc).

You may have to adapt the `Devise` methods - either with its `Warden` strategy, or its [`find` methods](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-to:-Scope-login-to-subdomain):

```
# app/models/user.rb
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, request_keys: [:x]

  def self.find_for_authentication(warden_conditions)
    account = Account.find warden_conditions[:x]
    where(email: warden_conditions[:email], account_id: account.id ).first
  end
end
```

The above code needs the correct request parameter passed through to Devise; you'll then need to ensure the `session` is only scoped to each tenant:

```
#config/initializers/session_store.rb
Rails.application.config.session_store :cookie_store, key: '_[app_name]_session' #-> need to add something here so paths will be used
```

--

That's an overall of how you'd do it. The above code needs tweaking but I am super tired right now, so I'll update afterwards unless you'd prefer me to delete it.

Comment: Looks promising. Would be interested to see how the session_store needs to be set up to support paths.

Answer (score 0):

A very simple implementation:

According to [How To: Change the default sign_in and sign_out routes](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Change-the-default-sign_in-and-sign_out-routes)

```
devise_for :users, :skip => [:sessions]
as :user do
  get ':tenant_slug/signin' => 'devise/sessions#new', :as => :new_user_session
  post ':tenant_slug/signin' => 'devise/sessions#create', :as => :user_session
  delete ':tenant_slug/signout' => 'devise/sessions#destroy', :as => :destroy_user_session
end
```

You can probably scope a session cookie to a specific path, but that won't provide any real security as the cookie is controlled by the user.

An alternative would be a filter in your `ApplicationController` to ensure that the user can only access paths containing his `tenant_slug`. This is assuming all routes for the user are namespaced under his own tenant slug.

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_action :ensure_user_belongs_to_tenant

  def ensure_user_belongs_to_tenant
    redirect_to tenant_root_path(current_user.tenant) unless params[:tenant_slug] == current_user.tenant.slug
  end
end
```

To include the tenant during authentication, you can concatenate the tenant's name onto `Model#authenticable_salt`. The default implementation from `Devise::Models::DatabaseAuthenticable` just uses the first 30 characters of the encrypted password.

```
def User < ActiveRecord::Base
  def authenticatable_salt
    super + tenant.to_s
  end
end
```